# Byte Buddy causes IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I use Byte Buddy (v0.5.2) to dynamically create a "subclass" of an interface (actually, I want to create a class that implements that interface). All methods invoked on an instance of this class should be redirected to another (interceptor) class.
I used the following code (with "TestInterface" being an interface that declares exactly one method "sayHello"):

```
final Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor();
Class<?> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(TestInterface.class)
        .method(any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor))
        .make()
        .load(TestInterface.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
        .getLoaded();
TestInterface instance = (TestInterface) clazz.newInstance();
instance.sayHello();
```

The interceptor class looks like this:

```
public class Interceptor {

    public Object intercept(@Origin MethodHandle method, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        ...
    }       

}
```

However, when I try to call the "sayHello" method (last line of my code example), I get an "IncompatibleClassChangeError". The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: byteuddytest.TestInterface.sayHello()void/invokeVirtual
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:448)
    at bytebuddytest.TestInterface$ByteBuddy$0E9xusGs.sayHello(Unknown Source)
    at bytebuddytest.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface bytebuddytest.TestInterface, but class was expected
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:965)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:990)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1387)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1732)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:442)
... 2 more
```

The problem seems to be related to the use of the "MethodHandle" parameter in my interceptor method. When I change the type to "Method", everything works fine. But according to the docs, "MethodHandle" should be preferred to "Method" because of performance reasons.

Is the error caused by a bug in Byte Buddy, or should I actually use a "Method" parameter in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Method` parameter and enable caching. That should solve most of your performance issues, if you have any in the first place.

See [javadoc](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/0.5.2/net/bytebuddy/instrumentation/method/bytecode/bind/annotation/Origin.html) for `@Origin`:

> ```
> public abstract boolean cacheMethod
> ```
>
> If this value is set to true and the annotated parameter is a Method type, the value that is assigned to this parameter is cached in a static field. Otherwise, the instance is looked up from its defining Class on every invocation of the intercepted method.
>
> Method look-ups are normally cached by its defining Class what makes a repeated look-up of a method little expensive. However, because Method instances are mutable by their AccessibleObject contact, any looked-up instance needs to be copied by its defining Class before exposing it. This can cause performance deficits when a method is for example called repeatedly in a loop. By enabling the method cache, this performance penalty can be avoided by caching a single Method instance for any intercepted method as a static field in the instrumented type.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer of Jeor which is totally correct (you should mark it as accepted). Just two remarks that do not fit into a comment:

You should of course only use a `MethodHandle` instead of a `Method` if the former allows you what you do. Invoking `MethodHandle`s implies some JVM magic. Handles are resolved with a polymorphic signature by a JVM, i.e. their arguments must not be boxed as the JVM will simply replace the call site with a method call. In your case, this does therefore not work. The advantage of a method handle is however that it can be stored in the constant pool of a class. It is a *native* concept that can be accessed by a byte code instruction. Compared to that, a `Method` reference needs to be produced explicitly.

You should therefore rather cache the `Method` instance (which is mutable!). Also, note that you are currently also intercepting the methods of `Object`. You can clean up your code a bit by:

```
Class<? extends TestInterface> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(TestInterface.class)
        .method(isDeclaredBy(TestInterface.class))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor))
        .make()
        .load(TestInterface.class.getClassLoader(), 
              ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
        .getLoaded();

TestInterface instance = clazz.newInstance();
```